# rmdir permission denied on mac

Tags: php, permissions

I'm running the following PHP in a virtual server on my mac:

```
$dir = './setup/';
$files = glob($dir.'*',GLOB_MARK);
foreach($files as $file) { unlink($file); }
rmdir($dir);
```

It's meant to delete all files in a directory called `setup` then delete the `setup` directory.

It deletes the files fine, but then throws the following error:

```
Warning: rmdir(./setup/) [function.rmdir]: Permission denied
```

I have read and write permissions set on the setup directory for everyone. What else can I do to get this to work?

Comment: You are running it into a LINUX virtual machine, right? Then it's not relevant if the host is a Mac or a Windows. BTW, is the folder empty?

Comment: 'I have permissions' - what does it means? Remember, **"you"** as a users logged on system is not **user** who ran PHP (i.e. web-server user) - in common case

Comment: It's the built in server capabilities on Mac's Mountain Lion OSX. No Linux. Mac folders allow you to set read and write permissions for 'me, staff and everyone'.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will do the trick:

1. Open Terminal on your Mac
2. Type "chmod 777 [path]" and press Enter. Change [path] to the location of the folder you are trying to delete, for example /var/www/folder, like "chmod 777 /var/www/folder"

Now you should be able to delete the folder.

Comment: This is not safe.